# Refresh text in tkinter message box constantly

Tags: python, tkinter, refresh, obd-ii

I'm teaching myself to code python on my raspberry pi. I'm using a bluetooth OBD2 scanner to and this code to get responses. I would like the message box to continuely update the RPMs. I've been looking for a while for a solution, but have been unable to fit.

```
import obd
from tkinter import *
connection = obd.Async()
connection.watch(obd.commands.RPM)
connection.start()
master = Tk()
response_RPM=connection.query(obd.commands.RPM)
msg = Message(master, textvariable = connection.query(obd.commands.RPM))
msg.config(bg='lightgreen', font=('times', 24, 'italic'))
msg.pack()
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a callback to handle RPM changes e.g. *update_message_text* and pass that as second argument to [`connection.watch`](http://python-obd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Async%20Connections/#watchcommand-callbacknone-forcefalse).

```
from tkinter import *

import obd


connection = obd.Async()

master = Tk()
message_text = StringVar()
msg = Message(master, textvariable=message_text)

def update_message_text(rpm, message_text):
  message_text.set(rpm.value)

connection.watch(
    obd.commands.RPM, 
    lambda rpm, message_text=message_text: update_message_text(rpm, message_text)
)
connection.start()

msg.config(bg='lightgreen', font=('times', 24, 'italic'))
msg.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, i am using mcp2515 with nodemcu-32s and am able to receive the messages which have few ids like 2c4, 2c1, 340 etc on the internet i see 2c4 is for rpm and i have verified it too. My question is that no matter which library i use to request the supported pids i send a message like this sendmsgbuf(0x7DF, 0 (ext), 8 (len), then data with 21, 01, 00 etc) and then i get a reply like 7E8,03 ( i assume len), 7F(negative res), 01 (for request), 11 (sub function wrong). I want to know that my car dont support requesting pid’s from it? Or is there something else which i dont know. Thanks

Comment: Maybe try get a list of supported pids first?

Comment: Well thats what i did and and i told you the response

Comment: Response: id: 0x7E8, data: 0x03 0x7F 0x01 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00